# Copy is not working in Ant Script

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I have one variable defined in my properties file:

```
require.extensions = html, htm
```

and I am using that variable as below:

```
<for list="${require.extensions}" param="letter">
                <sequential>
                    <copy todir="${dir.publish.html}">                                          
                        <fileset dir="${project.dir}">
                            <include name="**/*.@{letter}"/>
                        </fileset>
                    </copy>
                </sequential>
            </for>
```

I want to copy all the file with extensions html and htm to ${project.dir} dir to ${dir.publish.html} dir

But currently it only copies html files and not htm files. Why So? As i am getting html and htm values in @{letter} out side  but i can't use echo inside  so i am not able to check the value of @{letter}. Is there any problem in my code ?

---

```
<copy todir="${dir.publish.html}">
    <fileset dir="${project.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.html"/>                         
            <include name="**/*.htm"/>
    </fileset>
</copy>
```

If i do this it will work. But want to make .html | .htm should be dynamically get inserted.

Comment: Can you add this statement <echo>Letter @{letter}</echo>  after or before include and see what value is getting printed?

Comment: It shows me fileset doesn't support the nested "echo" element

Comment: And if i put it before or after copy its shows me copy doesn't support the nested "echo" element.

Comment: I am not sure why you are getting the error.I have used for loop and see this example   http://thecafetechno.com/tutorials/ant/how-to-use-for-loop-in-ant/

Comment: I am also using ant.contrib.jar and What kind of prefix is <ac: ? Is it require ?

Comment: Can anyone Help me out here. Please

Comment: ac is the namespace in the xml file and thats only optional....Try to check how you can enable the echo and that may throw some light...

Comment: Use the _verbose_ option, Luke. The `<copy/>` parameter takes the verbose option: `<copy verbose="true">`, and that will show you what is being considered for copying and what isn't. Another is to use the `-d` switch when you call Ant: `ant -d target`. This will print out a whole slew of stuff (so you might want to redirect the output to a file). The debug will show you what is being executed with your `<for/>` loop. Both will point out why things aren't working the way you think they should be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the [documentation of the for task](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html), the default delimiter usedto split the string into tokens is `,`. This means that your list will contain two tokens: `html` and `<space>htm`. So your task copies all the files which end with `.<space>htm`.

Comment: Yes! you are correct due to space it was ignoring the second extension i.e. .<space>htm . Thanks for pointing out and making me pretty clear.

Can we use trim here to remove leading spaces for each extension?

Comment: O! Yes. we have trim attribute with For loop